# mixins with multiple params - how properties are selected?

Tags: less, less-mixins

I'm reading [a manual](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) on LESS and there is the following example here:
`It is legal to define multiple mixins with the same name and number of parameters. Less will use properties of all that can apply. If you used the mixin with one parameter e.g. .mixin(green);, then properties of all mixins with exactly one mandatory parameter will be used:`

```
.mixin(@color) {
  color-1: @color;
}
.mixin(@color; @padding:2) {
  color-2: @color;
  padding-2: @padding;
}
.mixin(@color; @padding; @margin: 2) {
  color-3: @color;
  padding-3: @padding;
  margin: @margin @margin @margin @margin;
}
.some .selector div {
  .mixin(#008000);
}
```

`compiles into:`

```
.some .selector div {
  color-1: #008000;
  color-2: #008000;
  padding-2: 2;
}
```

I can't seem to grasp the logic behind selecting the properties. Can someone please explain me it?

Comment: The properties of mixin with one parameter and two parameters are used because the one with two parameters has a default value (`@padding: 2`). If you remove the default value then you would get only `color-1:...`.

Comment: Thanks, but the third one also has default value here `@margin:2`. Should then the default values have some order?

Comment: The third one doesn't get applied because for `color` there is a value passed at the time of calling and `margin` has a default value but `padding` doesn't have one. If you add a default value to that also (or) pass a value at the time of calling (like `.mixin(green; 2)`) then it would get used. Also, note that when a default value is assigned the second mixin becomes same as the first  , so both can be clubbed into one.

Comment: Got, you! Thanks a lot for you help! You could make an answer out of your comments so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quoting the LESS Manual:**

> It is legal to define multiple mixins with the same name and number of parameters. Less will use properties of all that can apply. If you used the mixin with one parameter e.g. .mixin(green);, then properties of all mixins with exactly one mandatory parameter will be used

The key statements are *Less will use properties of all **that can apply*** and *then properties of all mixins with **exactly one mandatory parameter** will be used*.

In the below sample, the output contains both the properties specified within the `.mixin` with **one parameter** as well as the `.mixin` with **two parameters** because the `.mixin` with two parameters has a default value for the second one (and hence is in need of only one mandatory parameter).

```
.mixin(@color; @padding:2) {
  color-2: @color;
  padding-2: @padding;
}
```

So in essence, when the second parameter is not specified in the `mixin` call statement, the rule/properties can still be applied because the default value would be used. If you remove the default value for the padding and make it like below, it would not get applied when the `mixin` call has only one parameter.

```
.mixin(@color; @padding) {
  color-2: @color;
  padding-2: @padding;
}
```

Similarly, the `.mixin` with **three parameters** is not applied because the `mixin` call has only one parameter and there is a default value specified for only one other parameter. So in essence, we have only two parameters with values.

```
.mixin(@color; @padding; @margin: 2) {
  color-3: @color;
  padding-3: @padding;
  margin: @margin @margin @margin @margin;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A supplement to the nice @Harry answer above, just the same thing but in other words (I just thought this "compact" form would work the best for a "technician" guy like me for example):

- `.mixin(@color) {...}` matches only `.mixin` calls with **1** argument passed.
- `.mixin(@color; @padding: 2) {...}` matches `.mixin` calls with **1** or **2** arguments.
- `.mixin(@color; @padding; @margin: 2) {...}` matches `.mixin` calls with **2** or **3** arguments.

The `.mixin(#008000);` call in the example has **1** argument so only first and second mixin definitions are invoked (but not the third).

Comment: Yup mate, pretty neat and compact while I had to use so many words :D

Comment: @Harry Yes, but it also needs to explain parameters with default values and how they affect things so that's why I marked my answer as a just supplement to yours as it has all this.